# The geometry of linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra

I found it in book "Linear Algebra and its Application" by Gilbert Strang. It is given as:

Suppose we have a system containing $n$ unknowns and $n$ dimensions.

$\Rightarrow $ The first equation provides $n-1$ dimensional plane in $n$  dimensions.

$\Rightarrow$ The second plane intersects it in smaller set of dimension  $n-2$ .

$\Rightarrow$ Assuming all goes well, every new plane reduces the dimension by one.

At the end, when all the $n$ planes are accounted for.

The intersection has dimension 0.

$\Rightarrow$ It is a point, it lies on all the planes, and its coordinates satisfy all $n$ equations. It is the solution.

I am not able to get the following statements. I would be grateful if someone please understand with a example...or figure ...

Comment: Look attentively to the corrections I have made to your text. It may be useful to you for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case where you have three equations and three unknowns.

$$a_1x + b_1y + c_1z = d_1$$
$$a_2x + b_2y + c_2z = d_2$$
$$a_3x + b_3y + c_3z = d_3$$

Each of these equations define a plane in $\mathbb R^3$.

Take the first two. If we equate them there are three possibilities.

1. They are the same plane. Since they are equal they have all points in common. This is a degenerate case.
2. They are parallel planes. Therefore, they have no points in common so the system has no solutions.
3. They intersect. They are neither of the above two cases so they intersect in a straight line. This line is one dimensional which is one dimension less than the two dimensions of a plane. This is the case referred to in the book.

Let's assume we are dealing with case 3 above and consider the third plane. Once again there are three cases.

1. The third plane and the line of intersection of the first two planes do not intersect. Therefore, the system has no solutions.
2. The line of intersection of the first two planes lies completely in the third plane. This case has an infinite number of solutions. This is a degenerate case and once again, not what is referred to in the book.
3. The line of intersection of the first two planes cuts through the third plane in which case it intersects at exactly one point. That point is the solution and has zero dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Take $n=3$ with a first equation $x=1$, which means all points of the form $(1,a,b)=(1,0,0)+a(0,1,0)+b(0,0,1)$ which is two dimensional. Then we intersect with $y=3$, it remains the points $(1,3,b)=(1,3,0)+b(0,0,1)$, one dimensional. And then a last step with intersection, for example, with $z=7$; it remains a single point $(1,3,7).$

Comment: Marie ::what is $a$ and $b$ here?

Comment: any real number. I could have taken $y$ and $z$ instead. Each "free" (to take any value) letter accounts for a dimension (physicists would speak about a "degree of freedom").

Comment: I am bit weak in plane ..!! i have a last question which will clear all my doubts ..can you please explain where $ a \left (1,3,0 \right) $ gone  in $y=3$ intersected with $x=3$!!!